# Extraction of different views of a pixel from 3D volumetric data

Tags: python, python-2.7, computer-vision

I have 3D CT data. I want to extract three different patches centering a particular pixel corresponding to three 3 different views (axial, coronal, sagittal). Can anyone please tell me how to do that in python?

Answer (score 1):

If your volume is I and the point that you want to extract the patch around it is x0,yo,zo and the patch size is p than

```
I[xo,y0-p/2:y0+p/2,z0-p/2:z0+p/2] = Pach1
I[xo-p/2:x0+p/2,y0-p/2:y0+p/2,z0] = Pach2
I[xo-p/2:x0+p/2,y0,z0-p/2:z0+p/2] = Pach3
```